# Auto adjust the UITableViewCell height depending on its contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to adjust the height of a cell depending on its contents. I know UITableViewDelegate lets you implement the

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView 
              heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return someHeight;
}
```

but I do not want to hardcode the height. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Of course there is. But how to do it depends heavily on what you want to do. If you want to change cell height depending on an image this is pretty straightforward, if you want to make the cell height dependent on newlines in a string there is more calculation. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I have a custom cell, which takes in either an UILabel or an UIImageView. Like you said, adjusting the height depending on the height of the image is quite trivial. But how do I find out how much space UILabel need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enter some code into that method that calculates the height of the row content. Exactly what code you need to put depends entirely on what kind of content you're displaying.

For example, if you're displaying text content that may wrap across multiple lines, you're  probably going to end up using one of NSString's `sizeWithFont:` family of methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your rows to have different heights, you have to calculate every row's height.

I've met such a problem. I calculated the heights of rows according to contents parsed from a json string. here's what i did.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // parse json
    id qWeiboContent = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    float totalContentHeight;
    QWeiboContentModel *model = [self getQWeiboContentFromJSON:qWeiboContent];
    QWeiboContentModel *subModel = nil;

    totalContentHeight += model.forOrComment.heightValue;   // comment text view's height
    totalContentHeight += model.content.heightValue;        // content text view's height
    totalContentHeight += 21 * 2;                           // 21 is height of a label
    totalContentHeight += model.imageUrl.heightValue;
    totalContentHeight += CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN;

    if ([model.type isEqualToString:REPOSTED]) {

        id qWeiboSource = [qWeiboContent objectForKey:@"source"];
        subModel = [self getQWeiboContentFromJSON:qWeiboSource];
        model.source = subModel;

        totalContentHeight += subModel.forOrComment.heightValue;    
        totalContentHeight += subModel.content.heightValue;         
        totalContentHeight += 21 * 2;                              
        totalContentHeight += subModel.imageUrl.heightValue;
        totalContentHeight += CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN;
    }

    if (self.arrayQQWeibo == nil) {

        self.arrayQQWeibo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [self.arrayQQWeibo addObject:model];

    return totalContentHeight;
}
```