# Best way to layout views with relative positions in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, layout, view

I have a question about user interface in iOS, especially on iPad.

My app displays restaurant information from a search result. Not all fields are required, so some fields are empty. They could be phone numbers, ratings, menus, and etc.

So basically what I would like to do is to display views such as `UILabel` and `UIButton` in a layout format, but I don't want to display any views with empty string. So there should not be any empty space between views.

The way I do is if a field is not empty, I initiate its view and then display below the previously displayed view by keeping track of the current height a view should be displayed.

Although this works, I believe that the way it works seems tedious. Is there the best practice for displaying views with relative positions?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do that is to use UITableView and follow what is said in this answer:
[Auto adjust the UITableViewCell height depend on its contents in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932088/auto-adjust-the-uitableviewcell-height-depend-on-its-contents-in-objective-c/3934119#3934119)

Comment: Yes I also tried this way. I think this is better in that I don't have to keep track of height. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 7):

I've created a library to solve just this problem: [CSLinearLayoutView](https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView)

You use it like this:

```
// create the linear layout view
CSLinearLayoutView *linearLayoutView = [[[CSLinearLayoutView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
linearLayoutView.orientation = CSLinearLayoutViewOrientationVertical;
[self.view addSubview:linearLayoutView];

// create a layout item for the view you want to display and add it to the layout view
CSLinearLayoutItem *item = [CSLinearLayoutItem layoutItemForView:someView];
item.padding = CSLinearLayoutMakePadding(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0);
item.horizontalAlignment = CSLinearLayoutItemHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
item.fillMode = CSLinearLayoutItemFillModeNormal;
[linearLayoutView addItem:item];

// add more items
```

Comment: The CSLinearLayoutView is a subclass of UIScrollView. I feel weird to add it to a UITableViewCell. So I'm wondering if you really use this library with UITableViewCell. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes, it can be used inside UITableViewCell, and I use it that way all the time. If the content is within the bounds of the linear layout view, it behaves just like a normal view without scrolling.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna give it a try! Nice library btw. Oh, and do you need to generate a dummy layout view in order to use it in  tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method? :)