# the height of tableview cell according to Content of UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I want to dynamically increase the height of tableview cell according to Content of textview in cell. Here I create textview and add that textview in cell as subview. So according to content of textview height of tableview cell  is get fixed. Any one know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto adjust the UITableViewCell height depend on it's contents in Objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932088/auto-adjust-the-uitableviewcell-height-depend-on-its-contents-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        int rowHeight =0.0f;

         NSString *temp = @"bqDHJIGQ BQWFVHWEF Q dsbkn  w jwh ndbvdhqd bdhjqdv dqvhdqvb dbqvwvhdqwwd bqwdhjvqwdhjvqwd bqdwjhqwdvbqwd q dbdqwqbvqwdvdw qwdhqwdvbqw dbqvwdjqwd dwbvvqjwd nqdjqvdjqw dwnqwdjvqhdq nwwdjqwvdhjqwd  qwdhjvhvbjd n qhjdvqdw dbqw wbdww.";

        CGSize size = [temp   sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];// calculate the height 

                 rowHeight = size.height+10; // i use 10.0f pixel extra because depend on font

       return rowHeight;
    }
```

Comment: very nice descriptive answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath{

    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);
    NSString *strTemp = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
    if ([strTemp length] > 0)
        labelSize = [strTemp sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 14.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return (labelSize.height + 10);

}
```